# Overwrite objects from arrays with map find and function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

People,

I´m practicing .map and .find.
I want to map arr1 and overwrite every object from this (arr1) with arr2 when the id matches.

```
<script>

const arr1 = [
  {id: '1', name: 'A', surName: 'A', age: 30},
  {id: '2', name: 'B', surName: 'B', age: 40},
  {id: '3', name: 'C', surName: 'C', age: 50}
];

const arr2 = [
  {id: '1', name: 'D', surName: 'D', age: 60, nickName: 'DD'},
  {id: '5', name: 'E', surName: 'E', age: 70, nickName: 'EE'},
  {id: '3', name: 'F', surName: 'F', age: 80, nickName: 'FF'}
];


let newArr = arr1.map(obj => arr2.find(o => o.id === obj.id) || obj);

console.log(newArr);

</script>
```

Result:

```
0: {…}
age: 60
id: "1"
name: "D"
nickName: "DD"
surName: "D"

1: {…}
age: 40
id: "2"
name: "B"
surName: "B"

2: {…}
age: 80
id: "3"
name: "F"
nickName: "FF"
surName: "F"
```

However, I would like to add the property nickName with value 'none' for unmatched ones like

```
1: {…}
age: 40
id: "2"
name: "B"
surName: "B"
```

for the resultant array: newArr

And I´m really stucked. I cannot find the way. As appremtice I will appreciate help.
Thanks a lot

Comment: are you trying to add the nickname to the returned objects in `arr1` where the id's match in `arr2`? Your question is not clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `coalescing` to assign the default value of `nickName` when `ID` doesn't exist in another array.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: '1', name: 'A', surName: 'A', age: 30},{id: '2', name: 'B', surName: 'B', age: 40},{id: '3', name: 'C', surName: 'C', age: 50}],
      arr2 = [{id: '1', name: 'D', surName: 'D', age: 60, nickName: 'DD'},{id: '5', name: 'E', surName: 'E', age: 70, nickName: 'EE'},{id: '3', name: 'F', surName: 'F', age: 80, nickName: 'FF'}];

var result = arr1.map(o => {
  var {nickName} = arr2.find(({id}) => id === o.id) || {nickName: 'none'};
  return Object.assign({}, o, {nickName});
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very nice. Only replace `surName` for `nickName` and value `''` for `'none'`

Comment: Updated the solution.

Comment: Btw con is that it has always length of arr2. Imagine when arr1 is longer than arr2. Same symptom as other short code solutions here :/

Comment: Didn't get you.

Comment: The current code won't return value with id 5 and id 4 in the result array. Do you want me to return all the unique id from both of the arrays?

Comment: Its not mentioned in requirements so..probably not

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id: '1', name: 'A', surName: 'A', age: 30},
  {id: '2', name: 'B', surName: 'B', age: 40},
  {id: '3', name: 'C', surName: 'C', age: 50}
];

const arr2 = [
  {id: '1', name: 'D', surName: 'D', age: 60, nickName: 'DD'},
  {id: '5', name: 'E', surName: 'E', age: 70, nickName: 'EE'},
  {id: '3', name: 'F', surName: 'F', age: 80, nickName: 'FF'}
];


let newArr = arr1.map(obj => {
  const match = arr2.find(o => o.id === obj.id)
  return {
    ...obj,
    nickName: match ? match.nickName : 'none'
  }
});

console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for set `nickName`= `none` you need change the `||` for `&&`. That's because in that operation you're asking about if those elements have a match or (||) the element `obj` exist. So, you need to change it or all your elements will pass the statements. I tried it doing something like this.

```
let newArr = arr1.map(obj => {
  let x = arr2.find(o => obj && (o.id === obj.id));

  if (x != null) {
    return x;
  }

  obj.nickName = 'none';
  return obj;

  }
);
```

Comment: I think you put `obj` because you want to know if it is different to `null`.